# undefined is not a function near $

Tags: javascript, jquery

Please tell me what's wrong with my code.

Following this example on jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/j8hc5yLm/
I'm implementing a virtual keyboard on my website when clicking on an input field.

I wrote this on my login page at the end of the html file

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#keyboard').keyboard({
    visible: function(e, keyboard) {
      initTypeAhead(keyboard);
    },
    change: function(e, keyboard){
      // trigger "input" required for typeahead to recognize a change
      e.type = 'input';
      keyboard.$preview.trigger(e);
    }
  })
  // activate the typing extension
  .addTyping({
    showTyping: true,
    delay: 250
  });

});
</script>
```

in the head section of the file I wrote this

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
```

In the page I have a div where I want to call the keyboard like in the example

```
<div id="wrap">
  <input id="keyboard" type="text" />
</div>
```

When loading the page I get this error:

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function (near '...$('#keyboard').keyboard...')
```

But I don't understand where is the problem.

Comment: If you look at the "*Resources*" menu of the fiddle you gave, there is not only the jQuery library to include.

Comment: You have to add other library files of `keyboard` plugin too. https://prnt.sc/ntxzlc  And https://prnt.sc/nty0ml

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because  This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers.